# How to animate marker every 10 seconds after cluster rendered?

Tags: android, android-maps-utils

I've added updated [android-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/) library in my project for marker clustering. I want to display clustering in map and i have done that.

The Issue is :
In my App, I have to display 100 - 200 markers, whenever its latlng change i will get update of new latlng for some marker.

1. if the marker not inside the cluster, i have to animate the marker from old latlng to new latlng.

Any ideas for how I can solve this?